# (PHP) Can't write to file, can only read

Tags: php, file, fopen, server-side, fwrite

I am new to PHP and am trying to practice reading and writing files. I am able to read the file and echo it, but I am not able to write onto it. I have modified the permissions of both the target file and the PHP file to 777 (all permissions). It keeps echoing the file contents without changing them, and I'm not receiving any errors.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

//rewrite file
$f = fopen("test.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $_POST["info"]);

//output file
$str = fread($f, filesize("test.txt"));
echo $str;

fclose($f);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what error is returned?

Comment: Have you verified that `$_POST['info']` contains what you think it does?  You can echo it just before your `fwrite` line to see.

Comment: did you tried closing the file handler after the writing and see if that works?

Comment: i think you have to reset your pointer with `fseek($f, 0)` before reading again.. also, to read AND write, you have to use a different wile mode, like `r+` or `w+` instead of `w` - see the corresponding php.net manual

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I have fixed the file mode. I believe it's a permissions problem, but I'm not sure which permission mode to set it to.

Answer (score 0):

First, you've to open the file in read/write mode. Take a look at [fopen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php)

Then, if you want to read what you've written, you must to [rewind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) the file pointer.

This code should work:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php

//rewrite file
$f = fopen("test.txt", "r+");
fwrite($f, "Rewind command sets the position of the pointer at the begin of the file.");

if ( rewind($f) ) {
        //output file
        $str = fread($f, filesize("test.txt"));
        echo $str;
} else {
        echo "Error reading file";
}


fclose($f);

?>

</body>
</html>
```